# Turning off an ESLint rule is not working, still get errors for that rule when linting

Tags: javascript, json, eslint, lint

I'm trying to turn off two rules on my linter, which I have running on commit. Our project is a pattern library and we have a lot of readmes that have many duplicate headings for our documentation, so I'm attempting to turn off `no-duplicate-headings` rule and the `maximum-heading-length` rule, like so in our `.eslintrc.json` file:

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:md/prettier", "plugin:mdx/recommended", "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["prettier", "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin"],
  "rules": {
    "no-duplicate-headings": "off",
    "maximum-heading-length": "off"
  },
  "settings": {
    "mdx/code-blocks": true
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.mdx"],
      "extends": "plugin:mdx/recommended"
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.md"],
      "extends": "plugin:md/prettier"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, even with both rules "off", I still get the same exact errors when trying to lint the files in question! What am I doing wrong here?

```
  191:1   error  Do not use headings with similar content (139:1) (no-duplicate-headings)  md/remark
  197:1   error  Use headings shorter than `60` (maximum-heading-length)                   md/remark
  199:1   error  Do not use headings with similar content (183:1) (no-duplicate-headings)  md/remark
  221:1   error  Use headings shorter than `60` (maximum-heading-length)                   md/remark
  223:1   error  Do not use headings with similar content (199:1) (no-duplicate-headings)  md/remark
  232:1   error  Do not use headings with similar content (206:1) (no-duplicate-headin
```

Comment: Is it being turned back on by your overrides?